# plt.hlines shows incorrect results when plot together

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

When the plots are done separately it shows the correct output;

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,2)
axs[0].hlines(5.,0,100,color = 'b')
axs[1].hlines(5.0000003,0,100,color = 'r')
```

[image]

However when the same plot together things looks very weird and doesn't make sense;

```
plt.hlines(5.,0,100,color = 'b')
plt.hlines(5.0000003,0,100,color = 'r')
```

[image]

Can you please help me to figure this out?

Comment: Look at the offset factor on the top left of the lower figure. That is the difference between the two numbers 5.0000003 and 5. This difference is so small that the graph y axis is showing the difference between these two numbers multiplied by 10^7 and that’s why the factor on the top left is 10^-7

Comment: You can explicitly set a wider range for the ylims, something like `plt.ylims(4, 6)`. The problem of being zoomed in too much will go away automatically when you add more elements to your plot.

Comment: Great thanks for the suggestions. I am thinking if I should remove this question or change the title as the tile could be misleading.